# Create button handler in F# for WinForms app

Tags: winforms, events, f#, click, messagebox

I'm trying to make a very simple application in F#. I want just to make a tiny button with the click event, which will call the `MessageBox.Show()` method.

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms

module FSI =
    [<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")>]
    extern bool ShowWindow(nativeint hWnd, int flags)
    let HideConsole() = 
        let proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
        ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, 0)

FSI.HideConsole()

let form1 = new Form()
form1.Text <- "App"

let Test() = ( MessageBox.Show("Clicked.") )

let button1 = new Button( Text = "Click Me" )
button1.Click.AddHandler(fun _ _ -> Test())

form1.Controls.Add(button1)    

[<STAThread>]
do
   Application.Run(form1)
```

The errors occurred for the:

- FSI.HideConsole() // warning
- button1.Click.AddHandler(fun _ _ -> Test()) // compiler error

And they are similar.

For the 1-st:

- Warning This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'bool'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 'let' to bind the result to a name.

For the 2-nd:

- This expression was expected to have type unit but here has type DialogResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# functions implicitly return the result of their last expression, so currently your function Test() returns the result of `MessageBox.Show(string)`. To create a function that returns void/unit, you can use the ignore operator.

```
let Test() = ignore (MessageBox.Show("Clicked."))
```

It's a bit cumbersome to have to do the extra parenthesis wrapping, so typically one uses the pipeforward (`|>`) operator, which doesn't require that:-

```
let Test() = MessageBox.Show("Clicked.") |> ignore
```

This can also be applied to your call of HideConsole. The compiler uses the warning to inform you that the return value of HideConsole is not used.

Comment: when I did as you told here, I've got new error: **Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized.**

Comment: Just edited my answer. You have to wrap the call to MessageBox.Show in parentheses.

Comment: thanks! it does work now, but the 1-st variant you've provided here doesn't work for me in VS :(

Comment: @GeloVolro See edit. (BTW first one works like that in VS2012 for me)

Comment: @RubenBartelink I've used the VS2010, but I have last .NET FW installed.

Comment: @GeloVolro So given that I removed some parenthesis prob no harm to verify that my edits work on FS 2.0 (or can you get to FS 3.0 in 2010?)